# Restart in Android - Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I learned to develop game using Libgdx for Android. The game is working fine if I am not going to set the "Do not keep the activities" in developer options. But When I set that option the App is closed and when I start the game it freshly starts.

I am trying to understand how we can save the data when the game reached onDestroy() and use the data to libgdx to restart my game from where I have left.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I hope the question pertains to the details on passing the details from Android to Libgdx modules